# Откзано в доступе. Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opengl, cmake, glfw

`[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На фото я предоставил саму проблему. Не запускается именно отладка, а собирается успешно. Этот проект я пересоздал из старого, переписав CMakeLists.txt для всех директорий, где они используются, создав новый репозиторий и заново импортировал все сурсы.
Что сделано: Исправлены права на все папки где логично было бы вообще трогать права, пробовал играться с настройками отладки и ещё что-то там правил по директориям. Пробовал скинуть все настройки visual studio к начальному состоянию. И потом, как я уже сказал выше, пересоздал проект. Я использую CMake для генерации проекта и Visual Studio 2019(Его компилятор) для сборки проекта. Помогите, не понимаю как исправить.

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.18.0 FATAL_ERROR)

set(PROJECT_NAME Test2)

project(${PROJECT_NAME})

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}
src/main.cpp
src/Renderer/ShaderProgram.h
src/Renderer/ShaderProgram.cpp
src/Resources/ResourceManager.h
src/Resources/ResourceManager.cpp
src/Resources/ImageLoader.h
src/Resources/stb_image.h)

target_compile_features(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC cxx_std_17)

set(GLFW_BUILD_DOCS OFF CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
set(GLFW_BUILD_TESTS OFF CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
set(GLFW_BUILD_EXAMPLES OFF CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
set(GLFW_INSTALL OFF CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)

add_subdirectory(external/glfw)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} glfw)

add_subdirectory(external/glad)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} glad)
```

Comment: Неплохо бы CMakeLists.txt привести

Comment: @dIm0n, добавил CMakeLists.txt по твоему запросу

Comment: судя по скриншоту, студия пытается запустить папку ALL_BUILD или файл без расширения, но  с таким именем. Логично получить ошибку в таком случае. Я бы проверил проводником ситуацию на месте и наличие бинаря.

Comment: Тут ошибка в использовании CMake для генерации проекта и Visual Studio. Сmake полноценно этого делать не умеет и сгенерированные проекты без ручных правок даже не всегда могут быть использованы для сборки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я погуглил проблему на английских просторах интернета и попробовал в свойствах проекта ALL_BUILD->"Отладка"->"Команда" выставить путь до Test2.exe. На российских сайтах ничего по решению данной проблемы не нашёл. Надеюсь это поможет другим

Comment: то есть, я оказался прав:)

Comment: Ну почти, ты говорил про наличие бинаря. Он был, просто путь к нему указан неверно. Мысли были в нужную сторону)

Answer (score 1):

Если надо просто исправить, то пкм по Test2, назначить в качестве запускаемого проекта.

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Ваш проект использует систему сборки CMake. Задайте свойство [`VS_STARTUP_PROJECT`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.6/prop_dir/VS_STARTUP_PROJECT.html) в главном `CMakeList.txt` для проекта, который вы хотите назначить в качестве запускаемого проекта.
Так же вам будет полезен [этот ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7304625/how-do-i-change-the-startup-project-of-a-visual-studio-solution-via-cmake/37994396#37994396).